# Why isn't Doxygen documenting public class functions for my C# code?

Tags: c#-4.0, javadoc, doxygen

I want to use Doxygen to document my c# code. So, I'm doing a trial run. So far it is not documenting the public functions in my test class. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @file doxyTest.cs
 * @author Jon Plotner <plotnus@gmail.com>
 * @version 1.0
 * 
 * @section DESCRIPTION
 * A test class for testing and running doxygen
 */

public class doxyTest{

/**
 * Method1 adds the two numbers
 * @param varA the first number to be added
 * @param varB the second number to be added
 * @returns An int which is the sum of varA and varB
 */
 public int method1(int varA, int varB){
    return a+b;
 }
/**
 * Method 2 compares the value of two numbers
 * @param varA the first number
 * @param varB the second number
 * @return A bool, true if varA < varB
 */
 public bool lessThan(int varA, int varB){

 }
}
```

In the HTML output from Doxygen the "doxyTest Class Reference" is empty save for these lines:

```
The documentation for this class was generated from the following file:
*source/file1/doxyTest.cs
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
The help is much appreciated as I've been trying to fix it myself for hours.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using, with the current 1.8.10 version I do see the output as expected. I used a default Doxyfile (except I set RECURSIVE to YES).

Comment: Thank you for testing it out on your machine. Good to know that my comments are fine and something else is the issue.

I am using version: 1.8.9.1

I did use brew to install Doxygen on OS X. IDK if that is a contributing factor.

Comment: I updated to 1.8.10, have RECURSIVE to YES, and I'm still not getting the public methods or functions described in the generated HTML files.

Comment: Did you create a Doxyfile from scratch (doxygen -g) or did you update your Doxyfile (doxygen -u) or did you just reuse your old Doxyfile and set RECURSIVE to YES ? Did you try it just with the above shown file or with your entire project?

Comment: I reinstalled and used the Doxygen GUI fronted; so, it was created from scratch. I had the input directory point to the folder containing doxyTest.cs which is the only file in that folder. Also, thank you for the continued help.

Comment: Ok, it works like a charm now. My mistake makes me feel stupid, but I had two copies of doxyTest.cs in two different files, one without the public function declarations, the other with. The one without the public declarations was not generating documentation for the default private functions. So, the mistake was on me. Thank you again for the help.